# Segmentation Fault Error (Using Pointers) in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

So apparently, when I compile this program on my own computer it seems to work. However, on another compiler it gives Segmentation Fault Errors. I've used pointers here, and I might have used them wrong, however, logically everything should work without error. If anyone could point out some errors, it would be greatly appreciated.

`contains.c`

```
#include <string.h>

int contains(char *s, char *t)
{
    if (!t)
        return 0;

    if (!*t)
        return 0;

    if (s)
    {
        char *k;
        int n = 0;
        int l = t;
        int len = strlen(t);
        int counter = 0;

        printf("%d", len);

        for(k=s; *k; k++)
        {

            printf("S: %c ", *k);
            printf("T: %c ", *t);
            if (*k == *t)
            {
                printf("Si: %c ", *k);
                printf("Ti: %c ", *t);
                t++;
                counter++;
            }
            else
            {
                counter = 0;
                t = l;
                if (*k == *t)
                {
                    t++;
                    counter++;
                    printf("Si: %c ", *k);
                    printf("Ti: %c ", *t);
                }

            }

            printf("%d\n", len);
            printf("%d", counter);
            if (counter >= len)
            {
                    n++;
                    t = l;
                    counter = 0;
                    if (*k == *t)
                    {
                        t++;
                        counter++;

                        printf("Si: %c ", *k);
                        printf("Ti: %c ", *t);
                    }
            }
        }

        return n;
    }
    else
        return 0;



}
```

`main.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int contains(char *s, char *t);

int main(void)
{
  printf ("%d\n", contains ("I wanna shoot something!", "thing"));
  printf ("%d\n", contains ("Let's get in range!", "ge"));
  printf ("%d\n", contains ("Wanna see the fireworks?", "wanna"));
  printf ("%d\n", contains ("Look at the pretty explosions!", " "));
  printf ("%d\n", contains ("Kaboom!", ""));

  printf ("%d\n", contains ((char *) 0, "aaa"));
  printf ("%d\n", contains ("aaa", (char *) 0));
  printf ("%d\n", contains ((char *) 0, (char *) 0));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fix your code until no more warnings are issued by the compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You assign integer to pointer and pointer to integer. It is wrong at least:

```
int l = t;
...
t = l
```

Comment: +1 This is the biggest hitch in this code, and running it on different implementations where `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(char*)` differ (or are the same) will exhibit the behavior seen. Changing `int l` to `intptr_t l` and including `<stdint.h>` is one *potential* work-around, but I would have to look more to be confident in that. In either case, the compiler should have warned the OP if configured properly.

Comment: I'm simply setting the location that t is pointing to to l as an int? Then I retrieve it later on... What's wrong with that exactly?

Comment: @Maaz what do you suppose happens when the physical size of a pointer in memory is *larger* than an `int` (such as a 32bit `int` and a 64bit pointer)?

Comment: So it's just a size of the integer that's being the limitation here? For example if I used long int or something, would that fix this issue? 

Furthermore, using `int* l = t` fix the error?

Comment: Since `t` is a `char *`, why would you use anything other than `char *l = t;`?

Comment: Oops sorry, I meant `char* l = t`

Comment: Seems to have solved the issue! Thanks a lot guys :)